# SQL select the nearest values with join

Tags: sql, mysql

There are 2 tables:

reference:

```
id  | score  | value | type_id
1   | 0      | 10    | 1
2   | 1      | 20    | 1
3   | 2      | 30    | 1
..  | ..     | ..    | ..
```

result:

```
id  | score  | type_id
1   | 2      | 1
2   | 7      | 2
3   | 0      | 3
```

I want to get `value` from `refernce` table for each `type_id` depending on the `score` in `result` table.

The query:

```
SELECT ref.score, ref.value, ref.type_id
FROM `refernce` ref
JOIN `result` res
    ON ref.type_id = res.type_id
WHERE res.score >= ref.score
GROUP BY ref.type_id
ORDER BY ref.id DESC;
```

The output in this case should be:

```
score | value   | type_id
0     | 8       | 3
3     | 25      | 2
2     | 30      | 1
```

But this is the actual output:

```
score | value   | type_id
0     | 8       | 3
0     | 5       | 2
0     | 10      | 1
```

So if the `score` in `result` table exists in `refernce` the `value` for this score and if the `score` in `result` table is greater than in the `refernce` table the `value` of the greater `score` which is 3 should be returned.

Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ecf1e3/1

Comment: Incomplete GROUP BY. For each group with the same `type_id` the server selects one indefinite row.

Answer (score 1):

use MAX :) to get the highest value ... and then join again based on those two values ...

```
SELECT ref.score 
, subsel.max_val 
, subsel.type_id
FROM (
  SELECT res.score, max(ref.value) as max_val, ref.type_id
  FROM `refernce` ref
  JOIN `result` res
      ON ref.type_id = res.type_id
  WHERE res.score >= ref.score
  GROUP BY res.score, ref.type_id
) subsel
JOIN `refernce` ref
ON ref.type_id = subsel.type_id
AND ref.value = subsel.max_val 
WHERE 1=1
ORDER BY 3 desc;
```

In case you are using some more sophisticated DB (Postgre, Oracle, ..)

You can use window functions to partition and order the rows .. and then only filter in the subsequent select the ones you need

Example (not tested)

```
SELECT score_ref
, value
, type_id
FROM (
  SELECT res.score as score_res
  , ref.score as score_ref
  , ref.value
  , ref.type_id
  , row_number() over (partition by ref.type_id order by ref.value desc) as row_order
  FROM `refernce` ref
  JOIN `result` res
      ON ref.type_id = res.type_id
  WHERE res.score >= ref.score
  GROUP BY ref.type_id
)
WHERE row_number = 1
```

Comment: What's the point of `WHERE 1 = 1` ? By the way  your first query is invalid , why see [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/). `In case you are using some more sophisticated DB (Postgre, Oracle, ..)` MySQL supports windows function starting from 8.0

Comment: no point ... just an old habit (for debug purposes .. used to work with SQL queries a lot back in the day) .... not sure what do you mean invalid .. it works and returns the correct result based on the example :) so I consider it correct.. if you say it's wrong, highlight the part which is wrong, state why and provide a correct solution (otherwise there is not point in saying 'it is invalid') ,,, re MySQL support - great :)

Comment: Sorry I am used to dbfiddle and I forgot to save the fiddle. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6vcNmW81Ca8Ck6XnvhBGQ7/0 . Invalid would be if sql_mode only_full_group_by is enabled which should be.

Comment: gotcha :) updated the query... I overlooked that ,, thx

Answer (score 0):

A solution that used only one subquery from joining the `reference` and `result` tables, where the `score` and `value` columns are converted to fixed-length hexadecimal string representations, combined and the `max` aggregation function is applied to them, after which the hexadecimal strings are converted back to integers.

```
select
  conv(substr(binstr, 1, 3), 16, 10) as score,
  conv(substr(binstr, -5), 16, 10) as `value`,
  type_id
from (
  select
    max(concat(
          lpad(conv(ref.score, 10, 16), 3, '0'),
          lpad(conv(ref.`value`, 10, 16), 5, '0')
    )) as binstr,
    ref.type_id
  from reference as ref
  join result as res
  on ref.type_id = res.type_id and
     ref.score <= res.score
  group by ref.type_id
) as t;
```

Result:

```
+-------+-------+---------+
| score | value | type_id |
+-------+-------+---------+
|     2 |    30 |       1 |
|     3 |    25 |       2 |
|     0 |     8 |       3 |
+-------+-------+---------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29f254/48).